# How to get the executable from Github

Tags: github, load-testing, vegeta

How to get the exe from https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta/releases in order to test in windows?

[This](https://kimsereyblog.blogspot.com/2018/12/load-test-your-api-with-vegeta.html) says I could find the .exe in this link but I don't.

I am trying to load test the apis in windows, as a start.

I do no know Golang and this project is developed using Go.

I would appreciate any directions on how to go about this. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

For this version they didn't provide an executable for windows. If you check one minor version lower you find a .zip with an executable in it. If you need v12.8.4 you could write the people of the repository or just compile the code by yourself.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like they only have executables ready to download for MacOS and linux on the newest version.

[Version 12.8.3](https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta/releases/tag/v12.8.3) however has a [windows download](https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta/releases/download/v12.8.3/vegeta-12.8.3-windows-amd64.zip).